SMTP delivery in JakartaMail: Get Queue ID from code "250 OK: queued as ..." server response
When we use Transport.send(...) to send a MimeMessage in Jakarta Mail, we don't get any return value (void method).
But I know my SMTP server responds to JakartaMail with a status line like
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as ABC123DEF456

after acceptance of the mail.
Is there a way to retrieve this SMTP response line to extract the Queue ID?
Maybe intercept all SMTP response lines and check if line.startsWith("250 2.0.0 Ok")?
